# Http Redirection code 3XX in python requests

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests, http-status-codes

I am trying to capture http status code 3XX/302 for a redirection url. But I cannot get it because it gives 200 status code.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://goo.gl/NZek5')
print r.status_code
```

I suppose this should issue either 301 or 302 because it redirects to another page. I had tried few redirecting urls (for e.g. http://fb.com ) but again it is issuing the 200. What should be done to capture the redirection code properly?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`requests` handles redirects *for you*, see [redirection and history](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history).

Set `allow_redirects=False` if you don't want `requests` to handle redirections, or you can inspect the redirection responses contained in the [`r.history` list](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.history).

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://httpbin.org/redirect-to'
>>> params = {"status_code": 301, "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/q/22150023"}
>>> r = requests.get(url, params=params)
>>> r.history
[<Response [301]>, <Response [302]>]
>>> r.history[0].status_code
301
>>> r.history[0].headers['Location']
'https://stackoverflow.com/q/22150023'
>>> r.url
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150023/http-redirection-code-3xx-in-python-requests'
>>> r = requests.get(url, params=params, allow_redirects=False)
>>> r.status_code
301
>>> r.url
'https://httpbin.org/redirect-to?status_code=301&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F22150023'
```

So if `allow_redirects` is `True`, the redirects have been followed and the final response returned is the final page after following redirects. If `allow_redirects` is `False`, the first response is returned, even if it is a redirect.

Comment: when we run the request with allow_redirects=False, this means to not allow redirects and page wont go to the redirecting page. So why it shows up 301 instead of 200?

Comment: @user2789099: Sorry, I am not following you. `301` is the redirect status code. `requests` always first gets the first URL; if that is a 301 redirect and `allow_redirects` is `True`, the response is added to the history list and `requests` makes another GET request to retrieve the new location, and so on. If `allow_redirects` is `False`, the first `301` is returned directly.

Comment: @user2789099: If `request_redirects` is `True`, what is returned is the final response. So the `200` is because `requests` followed the redirect and fetched the next page too.

Comment: I stumbled upon this while having the same issue using C#'s HttpWebRequest. All I had to do was: `request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;` and now I get the 301 I would expect.

Comment: @Ben that's... interesting, but C# and Python are quite separate beasts.

Comment: yeah I know, but it's not too surprising that they implemented similar logic in this case: "make a web request, if get 3XX status code, do redirect unless I am told not to". Just thought I would leave it here in case anyone had the same issue as me :-)

Comment: @Ben: sounds like you were looking for [How to get a redirection response](//stackoverflow.com/q/3836784) then.

Comment: @Martijn You are quite right! I stopped looking as your answer got me where I needed to go, but hopefully the link will help anyone else who ends up here!

Answer (score 11):

`requests.get` allows for an optional keyword argument `allow_redirects` which defaults to `True`. Setting `allow_redirects` to `False` will disable automatically following redirects, as follows:

```
In [1]: import requests
In [2]: r = requests.get('http://goo.gl/NZek5', allow_redirects=False)
In [3]: print r.status_code
301
```

Comment: the default is `False` for HEAD requests

Answer (score 2):

This solution will identify the redirect and display the history of redirects, and it will handle common errors.  This will ask you for your URL in the console.

```
import requests

def init():
    console = input("Type the URL: ")
    get_status_code_from_request_url(console)


def get_status_code_from_request_url(url, do_restart=True):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        if len(r.history) < 1:
            print("Status Code: " + str(r.status_code))
        else:
            print("Status Code: 301. Below are the redirects")
            h = r.history
            i = 0
            for resp in h:
                print("  " + str(i) + " - URL " + resp.url + " \n")
                i += 1
        if do_restart:
            init()
    except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema:
        print("You forgot the protocol. http://, https://, ftp://")
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print("Sorry, but I couldn't connect. There was a connection problem.")
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        print("Sorry, but I couldn't connect. I timed out.")
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        print("There were too many redirects.  I can't count that high.")


init()
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone have the php version of this code?

```
    r = requests.get(url)
    if len(r.history) < 1:
        print("Status Code: " + str(r.status_code))
    else:
        print("Status Code: 301. Below are the redirects")
        h = r.history
        i = 0
        for resp in h:
            print("  " + str(i) + " - URL " + resp.url + " \n")
            i += 1
    if do_restart:
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31345836)