# python requests handle error 302?

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests

I am trying to make a http request using `requests` library to the redirect url (in response headers-Location). When using Chrome inspection, I can see the response status is 302.

However, in python, `requests` always returns a 200 status. I added the `allow_redirects=False`, but the status is still always 200.

- The url is `https://api.weibo.com/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A//oauth.weico.cc&response_type=code&client_id=211160679`
- the first line entered the test account: `moyan429@hotmail.com`
- the second line entered the password: `112358`

and then click the first button to login.

My Python code:

```
import requests

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36'
session = requests.session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = user_agent
session.headers['Host'] = 'api.weibo.com'
session.headers['Origin']='https://api.weibo.com'
session.headers['Referer'] ='https://api.weibo.com/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A//oauth.weico.cc&response_type=code&client_id=211160679'
session.headers['Connection']='keep-alive'

data = {
    'client_id': api_key,
    'redirect_uri': callback_url,
    'userId':'moyan429@hotmail.com',
    'passwd': '112358',
    'switchLogin': '0',
    'action': 'login',
    'response_type': 'code',
    'quick_auth': 'null'
}

resp = session.post(
    url='https://api.weibo.com/oauth2/authorize',
    data=data,
    allow_redirects=False
)
code = resp.url[-32:]
print code
```

Comment: That's because you get an error; something is wrong with your request still.

Comment: To everyone pointing out the username and password: the *API key* is missing, and the OP stated this is a *test account*.

Comment: I also notice there is a Captcha on the page, as well as other parameters you did not specify. Have you tried looking for documentation as to what their oauth2 API requires?

Comment: this thread helped me
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150023/http-redirection-code-3xx-in-python-requests _italic_

Comment: Thank you for apprising me for the `allow_redirects` arg, I was not able to get the necessary cookies because the page that provided them was being redirected away

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably getting an API error message. Use `print resp.text` to see what the server tells you is wrong here.

Note that you can always inspect `resp.history` to see if there were any redirects; if there were any you'll find a list of response objects.

Do not set the `Host` or `Connection` headers; leave those to `requests` to handle. I doubt the `Origin` or `Referer` headers here needed either. Since this is an *API*, the `User-Agent` header is probably also overkill.

Comment: thanks for your response. I checked the resp.history, it's empty. and the content of resp.text showed that it still stay in the same page. But when I used browser to login this url, the redirect will happen.

Comment: @GuixingWei: so you are missing something else. Perhaps the page uses CSRF tokens? Perhaps you need to `GET` the login page first to get the session cookie?

Comment: appreciate a lot for your suggestion. I fixed this problem. Yes,your idea is right. I need to get the cookie from login page, and then use the cookie to get the authorization page. Thanks so much for this idea!!