# python urllib.request.URLOpener returns 301 response

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, http-status-code-301, urlretrieve

I was trying to download materials off the web site which didn't allow bots. I could manage to pass a header to Request this way:

```
url = 'https://www.superdatascience.com/machine-learning/'
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
soup = bs(res,'lxml')
links = soup.findAll('a')
res.close()
hrefs = [link.attrs['href'] for link in links]

# Now am filtering in zips only
zips = list(filter(lambda x : 'zip' in x, hrefs))
```

I hope that Kiril forgives me for that, honestly I didn't mean anything unethical. Just wanted to make it programmatically.

Now when I have all the links for zip files I need to retrieve the content off them. And `urllib.request.urlretrieve` obviously forbids downloading through a script. So, I'm doing it through URLOpener:

```
opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'    
for zip in zips:
    file_name = zip.split('/')[-1]
    opener.retrieve(zip, file_name)
```

the above returned:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 301: Moved Permanently
```

I tried without a loop, having thought something silly, and made it with a method `addheaders`:

```
opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')]
opener.retrieve(zips[1], 'file.zip')
```

But it returned the same response with no resource being loaded.

I've two questions:
1. Is there something wrong with my code? and if yes what did I do wrong?
2. is there another way to make it working?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: The 301 isn't an error, it's a valid response from the server telling you precisely what the problem is - the resource have been moved.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/22150023/7432

Comment: Bryan Oakley I've edited the question. Would you know how to handle 301 response within `opener.retrieve`?