# python request.get(allow_redirect=false) is giving me 302 instead of giving me what i wanted

Tags: python, python-requests

i wanted to pull a get request to a certain domain

lets say :

```
http://127.0.0.1/something.asp
```

but it redirecting to

```
http://127.0.0.1/default.asp
```

i followed this thread

[Http Redirection code 3XX in python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150023/http-redirection-code-3xx-in-python-requests)

from which i can understand what exactly is happening the *request,headers (location),and redirection and all*
but there isnt any solution to force
python requests to get that domain without a 301 http error response

for instance if i try to trigger that desired link
that is   `http://127.0.0.1/something.asp` in incognito browser
it is being redirected to

```
http://127.0.0.1/default.asp
```

but without clicking on any subdomains from that default page if in the search bar if i give the same link again

```
http://127.0.0.1/something.asp
```

this time without getting redirected im on that particular page

now my question is

if there is any way if thee site  is  redirecting(allow_redirect=True) and if the url isnt the same as the one i have given
it should request again with cookie( or whatever that happend when i tried in incognito ) so that i get that desired page

Comment: You should be able to find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22150164/13449866).