# How to let multiple web address (http) point to the smae webpage

Tags: python, html, http, web

I want 3 or more web address (http) point to the smae webpage, how to do so

in python or html,css,javascript way

1. http://192.168.0.206:8080/english/index.html
2. http://192.168.0.206:8080/english/apple
3. http://192.168.0.206:8080/english?fruit_ID=001

I have done the learning about flask, can command in web address, but still need a hand

is a concept question so that I don't post the code, I just need the key word for this idea, so that I can look it up too, or luckily if someone know ho to do, thanks

---

I have read through the discussion, the [Http Redirection code 3XX in python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150023/http-redirection-code-3xx-in-python-requests) was the closest, but that one not slove my problem

Comment: if the question is too broad just let me know, I will try my best to describe the idea I want

Comment: if you have multiple pages with the same content, it's bad for seo so you should have a canonical url and redirect the other urls to that page

Comment: Could you give more contect about the technologies you use? You mentioned Flask, do you mean you want a way to serve the same content at different URLs with Flask?